# Using a DatagramChannel for Multicast data in Android

Tags: java, android, multicast

I have a working multicast receiver on my Android enabled dev board (version 4.3) using MulticastSocket; what I want instead is to be able to use NIO channels. With MulticastChannel not existing in Android, I have tried to use DatagramChannel in its place without any luck thus far. If anyone has any information about configuring the channel to do multicast reception only, that would be awesome!

Heres some sample code that does not work, but will give a general idea about how I'm doing the set-up:

```
InetAddress groupAddr = InetAddress.getByName(groupAddress);
SelectorProvider provider = SelectorProvider.provider();
Selector selector = provider.openSelector();    
DatagramChannel dc = DatagramChannel.open();
// this cast fails
MulticastSocket socket = (MulticastSocket) dc.socket();
// set ttl
socket.setTimeToLive(16);
// set receive buffer
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(65536);
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
// join group
socket.joinGroup(groupAddr);
```

Yields this (which I kind of expected):

```
11-14 18:11:56.203: E/AndroidRuntime(22315): FATAL EXCEPTION: DatagramListener
11-14 18:11:56.203: E/AndroidRuntime(22315): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl$DatagramSocketAdapter cannot be cast to java.net.MulticastSocket
```

Comment: any luck with this? Have you been able to work this out?

Comment: Not so far; seems impossible atm

Answer (score 2):

Working code. _pairChannelAndSocket() method

```
public class Sample
{
    private DatagramChannel createChannel(NetworkInterface networkIf, InetSocketAddress address)
            throws IOException {

        MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(address.getPort());
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
        socket.joinGroup(MCAST_ADDRESS, networkIf);

        DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
        _pairChannelAndSocket(channel, socket);
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        return channel;
    }

    public static void _pairChannelAndSocket(DatagramChannel channel, MulticastSocket socket) {
        try {
            Field f = channel.getClass().getDeclaredField("socket");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(channel, socket);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it yet, but here's some thoughts about using reflection:

- Your DatagramChannel.socket() returns `java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl$DatagramSocketAdapter` class
- If you check the sources - that class provides `DatagramSocket`-like interface by wrapping the actual `DatagramChannelImpl`
- Using reflection you can get the `channelImpl` attribute of that adapter object, which is the actual `DatagramChannelImpl`
- Having the `DatagramChannelImpl` instance you can join/leave multicast groups

Alternatively, maybe try using `DatagramSocket.setDatagramSocketImplFactory` to assign your custom factory producing socket implementations with multicast configured. Or producing socket implementations that expose actual "Impl" object in their adapter.